# _URLFetchResult object has no attribute 'body' when calling Freebase via Python Module

Tags: python, httprequest, freebase

I've been using the Freebase Python module successfully to read data, and today I started testing writing data to Freebase.

But I keep getting an error that isn't making sense to me:

Within the same scope of code, I can perform an mqlread(query) without error.

But when I try:

```
freebase.mqlwrite(query)
```

I get an error like:

```
File "/Users/willmerydith/repos/supermeeple-sk/admin.py", line 96, in post
   result = freebase.mqlwrite(query)
 File "/Users/willmerydith/repos/supermeeple-sk/freebase/api/session.py",
line 745, in mqlwrite
   form=dict(query=qstr))
 File "/Users/willmerydith/repos/supermeeple-sk/freebase/api/session.py",
line 442, in _httpreq_json
   resp, body = self._httpreq(*args, **kws)
 File "/Users/willmerydith/repos/supermeeple-sk/freebase/api/session.py",
line 428, in _httpreq
   return self._http_request(url, method, body, headers)
 File "/Users/willmerydith/repos/supermeeple-sk/freebase/api/httpclients.py",
line 88, in __call__
   self._raise_service_error(url, resp.status_code,
resp.headers['content-type'], resp.body)
AttributeError: '_URLFetchResult' object has no attribute 'body'
```

Does this mean that those calls are failing to reach Freebase?  Or
that Freebase is not sending back a proper Result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is a bug in Freebase-Python.  I've filed the bug and offered a solution:  http://code.google.com/p/freebase-python/issues/detail?id=15